# Java App Bundler doesn't support Retina?

Tags: java, retina, app-bundle

I recently used the Java App Bundler utility to successfully create a Mac App bundle, with an icon of my choice. Here are links:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html (Oracle's tutorial)

https://java.net/downloads/appbundler/appbundler.html (documentation)

The created .app file successfully executes the wrapped JAR, but the application windows are always noticeably pixelated. The utility was written by Oracle quite some time ago, and I would like to know if there is any way to support Retina.